# Ender JS build without internet

Tags: javascript, ender

Is there any way to stop ender trekking of to the internet to get a copy of itself before building from local libraries?

Can I save a local copy of ender-js and tell it to use that?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just fetch the npm-library

```
 ender -b /dir
```